# How to persist SQL Server system table records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a query that returns the last execution time for a stored procedure:

```
SELECT 
    o.name, 
    ps.last_execution_time 
FROM   
    sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats ps 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.objects o ON ps.object_id = o.object_id 
ORDER BY 
    ps.last_execution_time DESC
```

I am getting the correct results, but if I run the query again in around 30 seconds, I don't get any results.

Is there a setting or command I need to set or add to persist the results?

My goal is to find out what stored procedures ran in the past 3 days.  I'm running this query against SQL Server 2019 Express.

Comment: Something somewhere is clearing your plan cache, probably using `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`. Another option is that you have Auto-Close, or you are actually using LocalDB rather than Express and getting an auto shutdown

Comment: So you get a result and in 30 second nothing changes and you get NULL back, and what happens when you run in that 30 secods a procidure?

Comment: Check the error log, do you see lots of `SQL Server has encountered %d occurrence(s) of cachestore flush .....`

Comment: @Charlieface I checked the error log.  I didn't see any cachestore flush errors.  I double checked that I wasn't running against localdb.  I also checked that Auto Close is off.  DBCC_FREEPROCCCACHE is not used in my command.  Where else would I check?

Comment: @nbk  I can get a result each time I execute the sp in that timespan.  Outside of it, I get no results.

Comment: Perhaps there is an Agent job that does it, or perhaps there is another command being run by some application.

Comment: @Charlieface - entries in the procedure cache will be evicted for reasons other than freeproccache. It succumbs to memory pressure just like any other cache does.

Comment: @user1647160 - what will you do with the information once you have it? I have a few ideas on how to capture that data, but the use to which it will be put informs which of them are appropriate.

Comment: If you want this sort of data to be maintained more reliably enable query store (assuming Express Edition has that). You can then query the querystore tables instead to get this info.

Comment: (In querystore query_store_query has the object_id column to allow you to select queries belonging to a specific proc)

Comment: @BenThul I'm using the information to determine what stored procedures are being used during an interval (2-3 days).  For display purposes only.  If I can export to Excel even better.

Comment: @MartinSmith.  Express does have this option.  However, I'm eventually giving this query to a customer who will run it against a 2008 db.  I was testing in my Express instance because that is what I have access to.  I apologize that my post did not indicate that.  I was hoping someone would see the version that I was running this against and say it was an Express issue.

Comment: Well there is nothing wrong with the query that you are running but `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats` is documented to only hold values for as long as the query is cached. Even if you solve it on your machine there is no reason to think that the same reasons for it being evicted from cache would apply on your customers machine. The query you have is only suitable for any purpose with the caveat that it only returns details for plans in cache. If this caveat makes it unsuitable add logging to your stored procedures so they themselves store details of their execution.

Comment: I wonder if I should just turn on SQL Server Profiler and trace my stored procedure activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest extended events for this. First, the session definition:

```sql
CREATE EVENT SESSION [ProcExecutions] ON SERVER
    ADD EVENT sqlserver.module_end
    ADD TARGET package0.event_file(
        SET filename = N'ProcExecutions',
        max_file_size = 10,
        max_rollover_files = 5
    )
    WITH (
        MAX_MEMORY = 4096 KB,
        EVENT_RETENTION_MODE = ALLOW_MULTIPLE_EVENT_LOSS,
        MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 30 SECONDS,
        MAX_EVENT_SIZE = 0 KB,
        MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE = NONE,
        TRACK_CAUSALITY = OFF,
        STARTUP_STATE = ON
    )
GO
ALTER EVENT SESSION [ProcExecutions] ON SERVER
    STATE = START;
```

You may want to modify the session definition to suit your needs. Examples would be:

- Filtering by a particular user (e.g. your application's login)
- Grabbing just a sample (e.g. "one in a hundred executions")
- Grab additional data (e.g. "what user called the proc?", "what was the whole statement (including parameters)?", etc)

Here's how to read the data:

```sql
IF object_id('tempdb.dbo.#events') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #events;

select cast(event_data as xml) as [event]
into #events
from sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('ProcExecutions*.xel', null, null, null);

WITH XEData AS (
    SELECT
        [event].value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2') AS [timestamp],
        db_name([event].value('(event/data[@name="source_database_id"])[1]', 'int')) AS [database],
        [event].value('(event/data[@name="object_name"])[1]', 'sysname') AS [object_name],
        [event].query('.') AS [event]
    from #events
)
SELECT * 
FROM XEData
ORDER BY [timestamp];
```

Again, this is very basic (returning only the timestamp, database, and procedure name). When I set about munging a new event session's data, I'll use that `event` column as a reference for what the XML looks like so I can write appropriate xpath expressions to pull the data that I need.